# Combine framework buffer operator with keepFull strategy: what does it do?

Tags: ios, combine

My testbed looks like this:

```
var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let pub = Timer.publish(every: 0.2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
        .scan(0) {i,_ in i+1}
        .buffer(size: 4, prefetch: .keepFull, whenFull: .dropNewest)
        .flatMap(maxPublishers:.max(1)) {
            Just($0).delay(for: 2, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        }
    pub.sink{print($0)}.store(in:&storage)
}
```

The result is just a slow steady stream of numbers in succession: 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...

But that is the same result you would get if you just deleted the `.buffer` line entirely. So what purpose does the buffer serve? To put it another way: can someone make me an example where a buffer with a `.keepFull` prefetch policy makes a difference?

Comment: "But that is the same result you would get if you just deleted the .buffer line entirely." - in this example, yes. But if you passed the actual value from `Timer`, then the first values would be ~0.2 seconds apart, eventually settling to be 2 seconds apart with the buffer, whereas without the buffer they would be 2 seconds apart right away.

Comment: @NewDev Can you write it out as an answer? I think I see what you mean, and this sort of smoothing is what I suspected was the point, but you should get credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffer "buffers" values up to its size, while respecting downstream's back-pressure.

In this way it provides a gap (a buffer?) between what the upstream sends and what the downstream is ready to accept. `Timer` would just drop values if downstream isn't ready to accept, but `Buffer` *is* ready to accept (up to its capacity with `.keepFull`, or always/unlimited with `.byRequest` prefetch strategy)

Specifically, in this example, if we passed the values from `Timer` directly, buffer would accept all the initial results (initial results would be 0.2 sec apart), before getting filled and settling into a steady-state (2 sec apart).

```swift
Timer.publish(every: 0.2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    .buffer(size: 4, prefetch: .keepFull, whenFull: .dropNewest)
    .flatMap(maxPublishers:.max(1)) {
        Just($0).delay(for: 2, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    }
```

Here's another example with `PassthroughSubject`:

```
let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

let c = subject
           //.buffer(size: 4, prefetch: .keepFull, whenFull: .dropNewest)
           .flatMap(maxPublishers:.max(1)) { 
               Just($0).delay(for: 2, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main) 
           }
           .sink { print($0) }

subject.send(1)
subject.send(2) // 2 would be dropped without the buffer

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
   subject.send(3)
}
```

That being said, it's not entirely clear to me what a good use case is for `.keepFull` vs `.byRequest`.

Comment: I have a good byRequest example, so we’re good. Thanks!

Comment: @matt oh, now I'm curious. What's a good example of `.byRequest`?

Comment: The code I started with. You can see it fill the buffer and then start dropping values while it waits for the downstream to request another one.

Comment: Okay so I think in my example the buffer is behaving incorrectly. It is passing the backpressure upstream. It shouldn't do that. It should have prefetched as many values as it could up front, immediately!

Comment: @matt with `.keepFull` it asks for 4 to fill itself, and then keep asking for extra as it releases values. `.byRequest` just asks for unlimited from the start. At least that's my understanding based on some tests with `.print()`

Comment: But that's what I mean by backpressure. Go back to my very first example, the one that emitted 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 etc. The upstream emits every 0.2 seconds. So I would expect we'd receive the 1 and pass it along, receive the 2 3 4 5, and now the upstream sends us 6 and it should get thrown away because the buffer is full. Instead, the buffer is exerting backpressure on the upstream. That's _why_ I couldn't detect anything interesting happening. That's _not_ what happens with `byRequest`; it doesn't exert any backpressure and some values _are_ thrown away because they arrive when the buffer is full.

Comment: @matt, right, that's my understanding too (now that i've played with it): `keepFull` delays the back-pressure until it's full, and `.byRequest` doesn't exert it at all. (the names could have been better)

Comment: OK, so you're saying we are to think that that is correct behavior. Thanks!

Comment: @matt. i have no idea if it's considered correct. ReactiveX could've been a point of reference, but I don't think there's a buffer equivalent there to compare (maybe I'm wrong). So it is what it is.