# How to queue or wait until last Combine request done?

Tags: swift, combine

I have a function that needs to only be executed once at time. I'm trying to avoid a function to be called while it hasn't completed the last request. Here's what I'm trying to:

```
import Combine
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

var publisher1 = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
var publisher2 = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

func scheduleNotifications() -> Future <Void, Never> {
    Future() { promise in
        print("Started scheduling... \(Date())")

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
            promise(.success(()))
        }
    }
}

Publishers.Merge(
    publisher1
        .filter { $0 }
        .map { _ in },
    publisher2
)
.flatMap { scheduleNotifications() }
.sink { print("Complete: \(Date())") }
.store(in: &cancellable)

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

If `publisher1` and `publisher2` fire, then `scheduleNotifications()` is called. However, before the function finishes, `publisher1` could fire and call `scheduleNotifications()`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    publisher1.send(true)
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
    publisher1.send(true)
}
```

This prints:

```
Started scheduling... 2021-02-07 15:50:25 +0000
Started scheduling... 2021-02-07 15:50:27 +0000
Complete: 2021-02-07 15:50:35 +0000
Complete: 2021-02-07 15:50:38 +0000
```

This is a problem because the `scheduleNotifications` is erasing all notifications before adding them. So the second request that fired one second later is erasing all the notifications the first request is still busy building.

Is there a way to tell the 2nd fire to hold on until `scheduleNotifications()` has completed any currently on going work it has finished yet?

Comment: how about use semaphore? https://fivestars.blog/code/semaphores.html

Comment: Do you mean, you want to execute `scheduleNotifications()` sequentially, with each upstream value? What is `scheduleNotifiations` - is it an async function? What's its return value?

Comment: That’s a concise way to put it, yes I want scheduleNotifications to run sequentially. It can run for one minute for example, and just returns a Void promise success/failure result.

Comment: @TruMan1, what's a "Void promise success/failure result"? Is it `AnyPublisher<Void, Error>`, or something like that? Can you add its signature to the question?

Comment: `func scheduleNotifications() -> Future <Void, Never>` but could erase it to `AnyPublisher`

Comment: @NewDev I added a working Playground example with more clarity and context. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `maxPublishers` parameter of `FlatMap`. Restricting to one creates a back pressure on upstream until the last produced publisher completes:

```
Publishers.Merge(
    publisher1
        .filter { $0 }
        .map { _ in },
    publisher2
)
.flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) {  // <- here
   scheduleNotifications() 
}
.sink { print("Complete: \(Date())") }
.store(in: &cancellable)
```

Comment: wow this works beautifully! it does actually queue them up, it doesn't debounce, throttle, or throw away requests. all requests are handled. I love it! thx again!

Comment: That depends on the upstream. `Merge` queues (apparently), but a `PassthroughSubject` would've just dropped values. You could always use a `buffer` upstream if that happens // @TruMan1

Comment: Your last comment was gold too.. I tested without the merge and indeed it drops requests until I add a buffer to it like: `.buffer(size: 10, prefetch: .keepFull, whenFull: .dropOldest)`

Comment: Ah looks like the `Publishers.Merge` has a default buffer of 3. If I add an explicit buffer to it, it will take my custom buffer of 10 for example.

Comment: Altho I can't understand what the `prefetch` strategy means. `.byRequest` and `.keepFull` seems to behave the same. wonder what case it would that difference would matter. The docs shed some light but a little confusing.

Comment: @TruMan1, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63257257/968155) and comments / discussion for a bit more detail. You're right - Apple's documentation could be clearer

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you use `append` instead of `flatMap`, you will get the result you want.

```
Publishers.Merge(publisher1, publisher2)
    .append(scheduleNotifications())
    .sink { print("Complete") }
    .store(in: &cancellable)
```

Comment: Good idea but didn't work as expected, it didn't let the first one finish, seemed to fire it in parallel (I plugged it into my working Playground example I updated the question with).